# Adding custom SQLite3 function using wxSQLite3

Tags: sqlite, wxwidgets

I am using wxSQLite3 (part of wxWidgets) to access a SQLite database. Everything works fine, but now I need to add a cutsom function to SQLite. Since everything in the code is done through wxSQLite3, I'd like to use wxSQLite3 interface to add the function and not the normal C SQLite API.
Following the documentation, I've declared a class that inherits wxSQLite3ScalarFunction:

```
class checkDateFun : public wxSQLite3ScalarFunction {
public:
    void Execute(wxSQLite3FunctionContext& ctx);
};
```

and override the pure virtual wxSQLite3ScalarFunction::Execute() method as follows

```
void checkDateFun::Execute(wxSQLite3FunctionContext& ctx)
{
    wxString date1 = ctx.GetString(0);
    wxString date2 = ctx.GetString(1);

    //some checks on dates

    ctx.SetResult(1);
    return;
}
```

Then, during database creation, I register the function doing

```
checkDateFun fun;
bool regOk = m_db->CreateFunction("CheckDate", 2, fun);
```

but when I later try to make a query that uses the function, I get this error:
"Exception thrown: read access violation. func-> was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF7".

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Just a note: `wxSQLite3` is a component built _using wxWidgets_, not _part of wxWidgets_.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
I had to declare `checkDateFun fun` as a member of the class that creates the database, and then pass the member to  `CreateFunction`. 
Indeed, I was instantiating my `checkDateFun` inside the function that creates the database, but the `checkDateFun` destructor will be called on exiting that function and further SQL queries will point to nowhere.
Hope this can help somebody, though I was making quite a stupid mistake ;-)